# How to get peer IP address in iOS app (iOS - non-iOS device peer-to-peer)

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, p2p

I am peering my iOS device with a non-iOS Direct-WiFi enabled device. In my iOS application, I like to initiate the connection with the remote server (i.e. the non-iOS device's server). To do this, first I need to bind my read and write streams to the host IP and port as follows:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;

CFReadStreamRef rdStream;
CFWriteStreamRef wrStream;
NSString *ipAddr = ???    /* not know at design time */
UInt32 portNum = 4210;    /* specified at design time */

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)ipAddr, portNum, &rdStream, &wrStream);

inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)rdStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)wrStream;
```

... then for each stream, I set the delegate, schedule in run loop, and open. Now they are ready for use. And obviously, in my iOS device, I go to the Settings built-in app and select the WiFi of the server I am peering with so my iOS device and the other device will be on the same network.

**My problem is** the server IP address is not known at my app design time, so I want to figure out this IP **programmatically** at runtime in my app. Is it possible? If so, please give me an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will get you an array of IP's. For my purposes the second element was the iP of the host name:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <netdb.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <net/ethernet.h>
#import <net/if_dl.h>

...

    const char* hostnameC = [yourHostName UTF8String];

struct addrinfo hints, *res;
struct sockaddr_in *s4;
struct sockaddr_in6 *s6;
int retval;
char buf[64];
NSMutableArray *result; //the array which will be return
NSMutableArray *result4; //the array of IPv4, to order them at the end
NSString *previousIP = nil;

memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;//AF_INET6;
hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
//AI_ADDRCONFIG, AI_ALL, AI_CANONNAME,  AI_NUMERICHOST
//AI_NUMERICSERV, AI_PASSIVE, OR AI_V4MAPPED

retval = getaddrinfo(hostnameC, NULL, &hints, &res);
if (retval == 0)
{

    if (res->ai_canonname)
    {
        result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:res->ai_canonname]];
    }
    else
    {
        //it means the DNS didn't know this host
        return;
    }
    result4= [NSMutableArray array];
    while (res) {
        switch (res->ai_family){
            case AF_INET6:
                s6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res->ai_addr;
                if(inet_ntop(res->ai_family, (void *)&(s6->sin6_addr), buf, sizeof(buf))
                   == NULL)
                {
                    NSLog(@"inet_ntop failed for v6!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //surprisingly every address is in double, let's add this test
                    if (![previousIP isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf]]) {
                        [result addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf]];
                    }
                }
                break;

            case AF_INET:
                s4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
                if(inet_ntop(res->ai_family, (void *)&(s4->sin_addr), buf, sizeof(buf))
                   == NULL)
                {
                    NSLog(@"inet_ntop failed for v4!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //surprisingly every address is in double, let's add this test
                    if (![previousIP isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf]]) {
                        [result4 addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf]];
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Neither IPv4 nor IPv6!");

        }
        //surprisingly every address is in double, let's add this test
        previousIP = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];

        res = res->ai_next;
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"no IP found");
    return;
}
```

...

Comment: Thanks for the code; however, this won't work for me because I don't know the hostname either. Let me clarify my question: I open the Settings app in my iPhone (peer 1) and go into Wi-Fi and connect to the hotspot from the non-ios device (peer 2). Now the peer-to-peer connection is stablished. So in order for me (peer 1) to bind my read/write streams to the host (peer 2), I need to know the IP address of the host. So the question is: if I am not told the hostname or IP address of the host, then how can I extract that info programmatically? Note that I can read the SSID and BSSID of the host.